# Spring Boot: Как прописать путь к пользовательскому файлу

Tags: java, spring, boot

У меня есть сгенерированный с помощью  jHipster проект. Пытаюсь открыть файл на сервере для чтения

```
private static final String FILEIN_NAME = "classpath:file1.xls";
....
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(FILEIN_NAME))
```

Файл располагается в каталоге src/main/resources .  Получаю ошибку,что файл не найден. Как правильно прописать путь и куда складывать пользовательские файлы?
Пробовал помещать в каталог src/main/webapp . Ситуация та же.

Comment: Здесь ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782924. Может кому пригодится